# SPI comunication - Only receive 0xFF (Linux)

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, linux

I've been stuck in setting up the SPI communication in Linux and can't figure out any solution.

I working with a beagle bone black, which runs Linux. I have a piece of code that send data through the SPI bus if I connect MISO and MOSI pins I will receive the data that I have sent (so far so good).

The problem comes when I try to connect with the sensor I want to communicate with, everything I receive is zeros!

I am pretty sure that the problem comes from the SPI configuration in Ubuntu (since I already could communicate with the sensor, using SPI, using an Arduino for the purpose). But somehow, when I try to replicate the same very code to beaglebone I can't communicate!

In this link is an explanation of how to configure SPI on ubuntu: https://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Enable_SPIDEV

I already followed the tutorial but the problem remains. Does anyone have some tip that must help me?

---

So, I already analyzed with the scope and I found that so intriguing, it's happening the follows:

- In the cs pin and sck it's having oscillation. Nevertheless, in the MISO and MOSI pins there is any oscillation.

What's intriguing me the most is that if I connect MISO and MOSI I receive the sent data, but I cannot see any variation on these pins. Any idea what's happening here?

Here's my device tree:

/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

```
/* identification */
part-number = "spi0pinmux";

fragment@0 {
    target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
    __overlay__ {
        spi0_pins_s0: spi0_pins_s0 {
            pinctrl-single,pins = <
              0x150 0x13  /* spi0_sclk, OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
              0x154 0x13  /* spi0_d0, INPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
              0x158 0x33  /* spi0_d1, OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
              0x15c 0x13  /* spi0_cs0, OUTPUT_PULLUP | MODE3 */
            >;
        };
    };
};

fragment@1 {
    target = <&spi0>;
    __overlay__ {
         #address-cells = <1>;
         #size-cells = <0>;

         status = "okay";
         pinctrl-names = "default";
         pinctrl-0 = <&spi0_pins_s0>;

         spidev@0 {
             spi-max-frequency = <24000000>;
             reg = <0>;
             compatible = "linux,spidev";
        };
    };
};
```

};

I am not quite sure about the definition of the OUTPUT_PULLUP and INPUT_PULLUP, I tried to follow the tutorial above the maximum possible. You can see the Beagle bone registers by searching for "Beagle bone registers" on google.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: problem statement in the title doesn't match the body. Are you getting FF's or 00's?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Yes, I receive only FF. Although I think that it's not the main issue since if I disconnect the sensor I continue receiving FF's (which means either the sensor is not sending data, or I am not processing it on the beaglebone's side.

What's intriguing is that if I connect the MISO with MOSI I receive the sent data, which made me think that the SPI is working ...

Comment: I read your title as Firefox (the browser). Make it 0xFF instead.

Comment: Are you using full duplex or half duplex?

Comment: I think SPI communication is full duplex. A send a byte and receive another one (bit by bit). For example, using Arduino I would do: int data = SPI.transfer("any byte"); and I would receive another byte in the MISO pin, the same in python. I am using this library in c++ http://exploringbeaglebone.com/API/  and it internally uses the spidev from Linux (which supposedly  implements the SPI protocol)

Comment: What device are you trying to communicate with? How exactly do you have it wired up?

Comment: SPI can be full or half duplex. Your link says both are supported. It sounds like you are assuming you are using full duplex. Make sure that is really what you are using, because if you're actually using half duplex you would see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Ok. But how can I know if I am using half or full duplex ? in the site says: "Using ioctl() requests, full duplex transfers and device I/O configuration are also available." I intend that the communication is full duplex. ioctl looks something like this: int ioctl(int fd, int request[], int send[], struct transfer). The struct has all the data about the communication ( speed, cs , mode, bits per word, etc )

The function returns the number of bytes sent.

Comment: Connect a scope and check if SCLK behaves correctly. And post your device tree.

Comment: @Fred Gomes Your description reminds me of an issue I had with i.MX6 Processors: The MISO had a pull-up enabled, but the slave device would not pull the line down, always producing the 0xFFs.

Comment: Try reading the datasheet/reference manual for your processor on the Beagle Bone. The pinctrl-single,pins section has config for actual pins, so you'll need to understand how are they actually configured.

Comment: AndrejaKo thanks for your answer. I can't find any reference to these configurations on the Beaglebone's manual. However, I tried to follow what's make more sense for me, so: CS and SCKL --> OUTPUT PULLUP and MOSI (sinse they are outputs), and MISO -> INPUT PULLUP

There is one more parameter which is "Receive active", I activate it on MISO and deactivate on MOSI.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/spi/spidev
It has a section on full duplex transfers

Comment: I already read the Kernel spi documentation. I've tried to figure out what's happening wrong with the help of a scope but it's been quite difficult to get a solution. The data is being sent  (the MISO and MOSI pins are exchanged, I don't understand why). With the scope, I see variations in the OUT line (bits being written) and the IN line is pulled to 0 every time. As I am "speaking" with a sensor, it may be normal in some cases, but not when the time for reading data in a register comes.

Comment: I have the SPI communication implemented on an Arduino and the MISO line is not pulled down, as opposed as on BeagleBone. Any idea why is this happening? I think it may be related with a parameter or kind of in the transfer structure that I have to send to ioctl function itself.

Comment: Hi there, I already found the problem. It was related with the spidev driver configurations and the cs_change from spi_ioc_transfer struct should be set to one (in order to do not have the MISO pin pulled up, don't know why).

Comment: The Beaglebone doesn't have fixed assignment of MISO and MOSI but rather two data pins with roles chosen by software.  Perhaps you've mixed them up so both master and slave are trying to drive one wire and nobody is trying to drive the other, which the Beaglebone might be looking for the reply on...